# Populate a table with "WITH" clause

Tags: postgresql

How to perform the following select query?

```
with x (x, y, z) as
((2 5 6), (6,3,2))
select * from x
```

I am not sure if this approach is possible. Not even sure if the syntax is correct. But I don't want to make a table in my database. Actually I am writing a PL/pgSQL function where I have few numeric values like 2,5,6,3 etc in few variables and I want to create a table from those variables so that I can perform some SQL operations on them.

Comment: [Related answer on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17247118/939860) This is just SQL, not specific to plpgsql in any way. And you don't need a CTE ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is almost correct. You need the keyword `values` and some commas that are missing:

```
with x (x, y, z) as 
  (values 
    (2, 5, 6), 
    (6, 3, 2)
  ) 
select * 
from x;
```

Comment: that was greatttt !! :)